# merge 2 dataframe with same but different case column in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes but issue is the merge "by" column has values in different cases.

sn1capx1e0001 vs SN1CAPX1E0001.

```
authors <- data.frame(
surname = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney", "Ripley", "McNeil")),
nationality = c("US", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Australia"),
deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 4)))

books <- data.frame(
name = I(c("tukey", "venables", "tierney",
           "tipley", "ripley", "McNeil", "R Core")),
title = c("Exploratory Data Analysis",
          "Modern Applied Statistics ...",
          "LISP-STAT",
          "Spatial Statistics", "Stochastic Simulation",
          "Interactive Data Analysis",
          "An Introduction to R"),
other.author = c(NA, "Ripley", NA, NA, NA, NA,
                 "Venables & Smith"))
m1 <- merge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name")
```

gives

> surname  nationality deceased title                     other.author
>
> McNeil   Australia   no       Interactive Data Analysis  NA

So I want to merge them by being case insensitive. I couldnt use merge or join.

I saw we can use regex to match values using loops.

Answer (score 5):

I found this pretty simple

covert both using "toupper()"

```
books$name<-toupper(books$name)
```

simple ....

Answer (score 3):

Why not convert them so they're of the same form?

```
library(stringr)

authors <- data.frame(
  surname = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney", "Ripley", "McNeil")),
  nationality = c("US", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Australia"),
  deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 4)))

books <- data.frame(
  name = I(c("tukey", "venables", "tierney",
             "tipley", "ripley", "McNeil", "R Core")),
  title = c("Exploratory Data Analysis",
            "Modern Applied Statistics ...",
            "LISP-STAT",
            "Spatial Statistics", "Stochastic Simulation",
            "Interactive Data Analysis",
            "An Introduction to R"),
  other.author = c(NA, "Ripley", NA, NA, NA, NA,
                   "Venables & Smith"))

authors$surname <- str_to_title(authors$surname)
books$name <- str_to_title(books$name)

m1 <- merge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name")
```

gives

```
   surname nationality deceased                         title other.author
1   Mcneil   Australia       no     Interactive Data Analysis         <NA>
2   Ripley          UK       no         Stochastic Simulation         <NA>
3  Tierney          US       no                     LISP-STAT         <NA>
4    Tukey          US      yes     Exploratory Data Analysis         <NA>
5 Venables   Australia       no Modern Applied Statistics ...       Ripley
```