# merge dataframe containing different case in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am having an issue where I need to merge two dataframes but the common column has different cases (some have upper case and some have lower case)

Example Data:

```
authors <- data.frame(
surname = I(c("Tukey", "Venables", "Tierney", "Ripley", "McNeil")),
nationality = c("US", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Australia"),
deceased = c("yes", rep("no", 4)))

books <- data.frame(
name = I(c("tukey", "venables", "tierney",
           "tipley", "ripley", "McNeil", "R Core")),
title = c("Exploratory Data Analysis",
          "Modern Applied Statistics ...",
          "LISP-STAT",
          "Spatial Statistics", "Stochastic Simulation",
          "Interactive Data Analysis",
          "An Introduction to R"),
other.author = c(NA, "Ripley", NA, NA, NA, NA,
                 "Venables & Smith"))
m1 <- merge(authors, books, by.x = "surname", by.y = "name")
```

Data is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101467/merge-2-dataframe-with-same-but-different-case-column-in-r)

I need to produce a result without changing the data i.e.

1) I do not have access to create a new column in the dataframe or

2) change the case in the dataframe or

3) create a new dataframe.

I understand that R is case dependent but some help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you create temporary dataframes before producing a result with no changes or does that violate your third condition ?

Comment: That's the way I'm currently proceeding with, I'll let you know if I find another way through. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can create temporary dataframes, I would do the following.

1. Store your data in temporary dataframes.
2. Create temporary columns with the transformations mentioned in your example.
3. Merge the temporary dataframes based on the transformations.
4. Remove unnecessary variables.

Translated in R, that gives.

```
library(stringr)
books_temp <- books # store in temporary df
authors_temp <- authors
authors_temp$surname_temp <- str_to_title(authors_temp$surname) # transform columns
books_temp$name_temp <- str_to_title(books_temp$name)
m1 <- merge(authors_temp, books_temp, by.x = "surname_temp", by.y = "name_temp") # merge
m1$surname_temp <- NULL # discard unnecessary information
rm(authors_temp)
rm(books_temp)
```

Note that it would be very hard to merge two dataframes containing information that require treatments without storing the intermediate transformations somewhere.